# Subscribe to Non System (Custom) Events in an Event Log

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

I want to raise an event whenever a new log entry is added to a particular event log file in windows event viewer. I am trying to do something similar to what is mentioned here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671202.aspx

**Here is my code:**

```
static void Main()
    {
        EventLogWatcher watcher = null;
        try
        {                
            EventLogQuery eventQuery = new EventLogQuery("C:\\Windows\\System32\\winevt\\Logs\\Admin.evtx", PathType.FilePath);                             

            EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventQuery);
            DisplayEventAndLogInformation(logReader);// this successfully opens the log and shows all logged events. 
            watcher = new EventLogWatcher(eventQuery);
            watcher.EventRecordWritten +=                       
                    new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(SomeEvent);
            watcher.Enabled = true; // here i get an unhandled exception which is as below:                         
        } //exception handling omitted here for conciseness

public static void SomeEvent(Object obj, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg){}
public static void DisplayEventAndLogInformation(EventLogReader logReader){}
```

I cannot use `PathType.LogName` as this is not a standard system log and it doesn't have a corresponding registry key under

> HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/EventLog

. This code works fine when I use a Logname like "System" or "Application" but it fails when I use their corresponding `PathType.FilePath`. I want it to work with `PathType.FilePath` and trigger events whenever a particular query(not mentioned here) is entered into the log. Any inputs on why this code is not working would be great!
Why am I getting "channel path inavalid" errors when the `DisplayEventAndLogInformation` method perfectly works fine?

**Exception Message:**

> System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException: The specified
>   channel path
>        is invalid
>          at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException.Throw(Int32
>   errorCode
>       )
>          at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.NativeWrapper.EvtSubscribe(EventLogHand
>       le session, SafeWaitHandle signalEvent, String path, String query, EventLogHandl
>       e bookmark, IntPtr context, IntPtr callback, Int32 flags)
>          at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogWatcher.StartSubscribing()
>          at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogWatcher.set_Enabled(Boolean
>   val
>       ue)
>          at eventlogreader.Program.Main() in C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio
>        2010\Projects\eventlogreader\eventlogreader\Program.cs:line 40
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args
>       )
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySec
>       urity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionCo
>       ntext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, C
>       ontextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, C
>       ontextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: You aren't really asking a question. Its more like you are stating your findings. Why not use their names if that does work? If its not a system log, then is it handled by Windows event log? If its not, I doubt whether it will raise any events you are subscribing to. A FileWatcher could be more useful than.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the post to make my question clearer. I couldn't use the name, it doesn't detect the log i am interested in because it's not located in the default registry space. It's not a windows "system" log per se, it's from a third party windows service/app. I have the Filewatcher implementation already but it is not efficient/reliable , also it won't particularly trigger an event when a certain value/eventID is added to the log file.

Comment: Similar question with answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292197/reading-security-events-for-applocker-from-event-viewer/53931085#53931085