# Reading security events for AppLocker from Event Viewer

Tags: c#

In C#, is there any way to read the security events for AppLocker (which is located at Applications and Service Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Applocker) application from event viewer?

EventLogWatcher fails to subscribe to incoming events for this Application.

Iam facing exactly the same issue mentioned here:
[Subscribe to Non System (Custom) Events in an Event Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142557/subscribe-to-non-system-custom-events-in-an-event-log)

Answer (score 1):

1. There are difference between (a) Event Logs and (b) Channels in Windows Event Log

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa385225(v=vs.85)

2. "Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL" is a channel
3. Use class `EventLogWatcher` for catch event in channel

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogwatcher

Sample on C#:

```
    var bbb = new EventLogWatcher("Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL");
    bbb.EventRecordWritten += Bbb_EventRecordWritten;
    bbb.Enabled = true;
```

...

```
        private void Bbb_EventRecordWritten(object sender, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs e)
        {
            var eventAsXml = e.EventRecord.ToXml();
            var eventAsString = e.EventRecord.FormatDescription();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this as a comment but I don't have the rep. The following is powershell we use to fetch these events in some of our reporting.

Get-WinEvent "Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL" |
Where-Object { $*.Id -eq 8003 -or $*.Id -eq 8004 } |
ForEach-Object { }

Comment: The request was for a way of reading events in C#, not PowerShell

Comment: As stated in the "answer," I didn't have the rep to make it a comment but thought it could be germane to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

FYI above powershell is incorrect (underscore missing) ..
BTW- Added computer param so you can retrieve remote computers' events..

Also event codes you want for audit are 8003,8006 & 8028 - the stuff "would" have been blocked, which you'll need to add exclusions for if needed.
Improved 1liner below...

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName server1-FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL","Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/MSI and Script","Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/Packaged app-Deployment","Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/Packaged app-execution";Id=8006,8003,8028}  | select id,logname,TimeCreated,LevelDisplayName,Message|ft
```

info on event codes: https://system32.eventsentry.com/applocker/events